# Using Applescript to zip and unzip a folder

Tags: zip, applescript

I have never used applescript before and I'm trying to find out how to zip a folder on the desktop, that's all and it's giving me a hard time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use Applescript to just invoke sh, you can use

```
do shell script "zip /Users/you/Desktop/out.zip /Users/you/Desktop/in.file"
do shell script "unzip -f /Users/you/out.zip"
```

(The `-f` option is "freshen", which will stop `unzip` from asking if you want to overwrite files. To always overwrite, use `-o`.)

Comment: omg, I don't believe it, i've been doing all this complicated rubbish but this works so perfectly ...I truely am an applescript noob, thank you

Comment: one more thing is there a way to use an equivalent of the cvf to show the progress?

Comment: `unzip` has `-l` for listing files and `-v` for verbose. `zip` has `-v` verbose as well, and `-dd` which will print a dot for every 10MB zipped (you can change it to other sizes with `-ds`).

Comment: What if I don't know the name of a zip?