# How do I use Applescript to unzip all .zip files in a folder?

Tags: applescript, workflow, unzip

I have a folder that's automatically given daily zip files. These only contain one file within them. **How do I use Applescript to unzip these,** regardless of their name and how many there may be?

Comment: I've already looked at questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183294/using-applescript-to-zip-and-unzip-a-folder, but they assume you only unzip one file, or that you already know the name.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to iterate through all of the .zip files in a chosen folder:

```
set thisFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder" to set allZips to every file in folder thisFolder whose name extension contains "zip"

repeat with eachZipFile in allZips
    set unzipThis to quoted form of (POSIX path of (eachZipFile as text))
    set destinationFolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of (thisFolder as text))
    do shell script "unzip -d " & destinationFolder & space & unzipThis
end repeat
```

This version forces the unzipped files to be preserved in the same directory as the .zip files.  You can always choose a different folder as the destination.

The Man page for unzip indicates that you can also use the * wildcard character to unzip, so this should work as well:

```
set thisFolder to choose folder
set destinationFolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of (thisFolder as text))
set wildcardUnzip to quoted form of ((POSIX path of (thisFolder as text)) & "*")
do shell script "unzip -d " & destinationFolder & space & wildcardUnzip
```

Comment: Looks rad! Any way to remove the residual .zip files?

Comment: You want to delete the original .zip files?  Is that correct?

Comment: after they're unzipped, yes. If that's not too much trouble

Comment: That should not be difficult, but I am away from a computer for a few days.  Could you please check your machine for a folder entitled _MACOSX or similar after the un-zipping?  I saw that on my laptop after I had posted the script.  Very weird.